# How to validate my YOLO model trained on custom data set?

Tags: validation, object-detection, yolov4

I am doing my research regarding object detection using YOLO although I am from civil engineering field and not familiar with computer science. My advisor is asking me to validate my YOLO detection model trained on custom dataset. But my problem is I really don't know how to validate my model. So, please kindly point me out how to validate my model.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think first you need to make sure that all the cases you are interested in (location of objects, their size, general view of the scene, etc) are represented in your custom dataset - in other words, the collected data reflects your task. You can discuss it with your advisor. Main rule - you label data qualitatively in same manner as you want to see it on the output. more information can be found [here](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-to-detect-your-custom-objects)

It's really important - garbage in, garbage out, the quality of output of your trained model is determined by the quality of the input (labelled data)

If this is done, it is common practice to split your data into training and test sets. During model training only train set is used, and you can later validate the quality (generalizing ability, robustness, etc) on data that the model did not see - on the test set. It's also important, that this two subsets don't overlap - than your model will be overfitted and the model will not perform the tasks properly.

Than you can train few different models (with some architectural changes for example) on the same train set and validate them on the same test set, and this is a regular validation process.

Comment: Thank you for your sharing. Moreover, I would like to know how I can modify the original YOLOv4? In the previous research, some changed the activation function and some changed the backbone network. Here, for the one who is lack of computer science knowledge, what should I try to modify the YOLO to be easy for me? Or please point me out if there are some reference regarding modifying YOLO.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply!

YOLO with original architecture is itself good baseline solution - try to train it first

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I've already trained the original YOLOv4. I prefer to improve the accuracy and want to modify the original one. Which part should I modify? Could you recommend for me...please.

Comment: It's hard to say something if I don't see the data and evaluation results, and I think it's already a theme for another stackoverflow question - try to make one